# Bilinear forms on normed vector spaces

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces, bilinear-form

For a positive definite bilinear form a: $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by:
$$a(x,y)=\sum^n_{i,j=1}a_{ij}x_{i}y_{j}$$
$a_{ij}\in \mathbb{R}\ x,y,$ two vectors of length $n$, prove that:
$$a(x,x)\ge \alpha\lVert x \rVert_2^2 \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n\quad\alpha>0$$
After rewriting a bit we can see, that it is equivalent to saying that
$$a\left(\frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert_2},\frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert_2}\right) \ge \alpha$$
Doesn't this already show that due to the bilinearity, such an $\alpha$ exists, since we can always pick it such a way, that:$$\alpha = \frac 1{\lVert x\rVert_2^2}a(x,x)$$or if need be:
$$\alpha = \frac 1 {\lVert x\rVert_2^2+1}a(x,x)$$
to ensure that it is less than the bilinear form? Since all factors are $>0$ it seems to me like it would work but it is so simple that I'm uncertain about it. Is there anything I overlooked/missed?

Comment: How do you know the minimum of your "function" $x\mapsto \frac{a(x,x)}{||x||^2}$ is not $0$ ? Try to use spectral theorem.

Comment: $\alpha$ is not supposed to depend on $x$

Answer (score 2):

Reducing the problem to vectors of norm $1$ is the first step. The second step is to notice that your bilinear form has a positive minimum on the unit sphere
$\mathbb{S}^{n-1}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\|x\|=1\}$, because it is continuous and the unit sphere is compact.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite follow, could you elaborate on that, please?